# How do I write an "is power of 2" predicate in ACSL?

Tags: frama-c, acsl

My attempt to write an ACSL predicate to see if an integer is a power of 2 goes like this:

```
/*@
  predicate positive_power_of_2 (integer i) =
    i > 0 &&
    (i == 1 || ((i & 1) == 0 && positive_power_of_2 (i >> 1)));
 */
```

However when I added some assert lines into a random function, some Timeout (ie. fail).  I don't understand why?

```
//@ assert positive_power_of_2 (1);  // Timeout
//@ assert positive_power_of_2 (2);  // Valid
//@ assert positive_power_of_2 (4);  // Valid
//@ assert !positive_power_of_2 (7); // Timeout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, for such purely logic properties, you can use `lemma`s instead of `assert`, as in `//@ lemma pow2_1: positive_power_of_2(1);`. Since a `lemma` is a global annotation, it spares you from writing a function just for the sake of holding an `assert`.

Now back to the issue itself. Mixing bitwise operations with arithmetic ones (the less-than comparison) tends to confuse automated theorem provers. You did not specify which one(s) you use, but if you only used one, you might want to try installing others (nowadays, a mix of alt-ergo, z3 and cvc4 tends to provide good results). That said, a small interactive help to WP's internal simplifier QED is also sufficient: by using the GUI (see section 2.4 of [WP manual](https://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-wp-manual.pdf)), you can conclude by just unfolding the definition of `positive_power_of_2` in each of the goals (as far as I know, there's no command-line option to do the equivalent).

Basically, once you are in the `WP Proofs` panel of the GUI, you have to double click in the `Script` column of the row corresponding to the proof obligation you want to work on, which will let you enter the interactive proof mode, as in the screenshot below:

[image: WP interactive proof mode in Frama-C GUI]

Now, the point is that the list of available tactics (on the right) is contextual: only the ones that are relevant for the term you have selected in the proof obligation (on the left) are shown. Some tactics are always relevant, such as `Cut`, which let you prove an auxiliary statement that can be used as an hypothesis in the rest of the proof, but unfolding a definition only makes sense if there's a definition to unfold in your selection. Hence you have to click on `P_positive_power_of_2` to let the tactic appear. Afterwards, just click on the corresponding triangle to let WP unfold the definition and attempt to complete the proof afterwards.

Comment: alt-ergo 2.2.0, but I also have z3 and gappa installed (it seems to always prefer alt-ergo for reasons I can't understand).

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "you can conclude by just unfolding the definition of positive_power_of_2 in each of the goals"?  Where in the GUI is this exactly?

Comment: Of course. WP's interactive proof interface is not the most ergonomic piece of software I have ever seen to say the least. I hope my explanations are sufficient, I'm afraid I'd need a full video instead of a single image to make things as clear as possible.

Comment: Yes I was able to prove the simple is-power-of-2(N) for small constant N this way.  I am doing this as part of trying to prove an actual C function, but I'm going to start a new question for that.